# jquery open id login plugin for gae

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, openid

I think this question might not fit in SO as per its guidelines but i feel this information would be useful for others like me

Which jquery or javascript based open id plugin would you recommend for use in GAE (python)

I have seen the one mentioned on the [GAE docs page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid#su) but it appears that it has not been updated since years

```
http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml
```

Or Would it be a better idea to write one myself

Comment: Open ID isn't that complicated, if you have the skills and the time you might as well roll your own, and if it's for log in with Google, they do provide scripts and API's that are generally OK to work with.

Comment: Thanks adeneo for your reply.. i wanted a plugin so that the present and future (popular) Open ID providers would automatically be incorporated.. also if there is any change the open id login url, that could be taken care of better..

Comment: most likely i would go ahead with your suggestion to build on my own but i would keep this question open so as to get any valuable advice..

Comment: This question as you already mentioned is off topic so it will be closed sooner or later.. But in general there is no standard way of achieving what you want and it really depends on many things like what you are using in the backend.. since the front end is not that important if you want to do it securely and stuff.. You can check my open source project that has plenty of auth options.. and you can see it in action: http://gae-init.appspot.com/signin/